# Object XmlSerialization with protected property setters

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Here is my object

```
    [Serializable()]
    public class PersistentObject
    {
        public virtual int ID {
            get { return id; }
            protected set { id = value;}
        }
        ...
     }
```

When I try to serialize this to xml, I get an error "The Property or indexer PersistentObject.ID cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible" .  If the setter doesn't exist, it works fine.  I want to keep this ID as serialized without a hacktastic solution that involves an of [XmlIgnore()] on ID.  I would prefer if I could add [XmlIgnore()] on just the setter, but the compiler complains.  Anybody have a *good* solution around this?

Comment: (note I added an extra option juts as you clicked "accept")

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. `XmlSerializer` has some things that are... irritating. This is one of them. Options:

- use `DataContractSerializer` (which supports `protected` etc, but **doesn't** offer full xml control)
- annotate with `[XmlIgnore]` - nothing wrong with it
- implement `IXmlSerializable` - hard work and very easy to get wrong
- take off the setter, and have a *separate* `protected` method to set the value
- use the `XmlSerializer` constructor that lets you specify everything at runtime; lots of work/maintenance, and you need to manually cache the serializer (otherwise it creates lots of dynamic assemblies)

Answer (score 8):

Even though it doesn't directly answer your question, note that you can serialize properties with an `internal` setter. To do that, you need to pre-generate the XML serialization assembly with Sgen.exe, and declare that assembly as "friend" using the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute :

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("MyAssembly.XmlSerializers")]
```