# Webservice error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, runtime-error, webmethod

I have a Webservice which builds just fine. But when I try debugging it and hit F5 (in Visual Studio) then I am getting error as `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. With reading more of stack trace it looks like the error is in a Class object that I am using as arguments for my `WebMethod`. The class looks like this:

```
public class UserObject
{
    public string UniqueID { get; set; }
    public string Password { protected internal get; set; }
    public bool IsNew { get; protected internal set; }
    public string Error { get; protected internal set; }
    public bool HasError
    {
        get
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Error);
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect this is the class which is failing to serialize. If it looks a blunder serialization object then its possible. Its first time I am in making of webservice. I may consider later to convert it into WCF. Placing `[Serialization]` attribute also does not work. Any directions from here?

And could anyone tell me how to trace exact error?

**Edit**

Below is the complete error.

```
    [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   System.Xml.Serialization.StructModel.CheckPropertyRead(PropertyInfo propertyInfo) +40
   System.Xml.Serialization.StructModel.GetPropertyModel(PropertyInfo propertyInfo) +44
   System.Xml.Serialization.StructModel.GetFieldModel(MemberInfo memberInfo) +89
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter) +247
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(StructModel model, String ns, Boolean openModel, XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter limiter) +378
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +1734

[InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'Presenter.UserObject'.]
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +1852
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportAccessorMapping(MemberMapping accessor, FieldModel model, XmlAttributes a, String ns, Type choiceIdentifierType, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +5539216
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMemberMapping(XmlReflectionMember xmlReflectionMember, String ns, XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +869
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, String ns, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +286

[InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting 'userObject'.]
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, String ns, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) +899
   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(String elementName, String ns, XmlReflectionMember[] members, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, XmlMappingAccess access) +133
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapReflector.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionImporter xmlImporter, SoapReflectionImporter soapImporter, Boolean serviceDefaultIsEncoded, Boolean rpc, SoapBindingUse use, SoapParameterStyle paramStyle, String elementName, String elementNamespace, Boolean nsIsDefault, XmlReflectionMember[] members, Boolean validate, Boolean openModel, String key, Boolean writeAccess) +235
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapReflector.ReflectMethod(LogicalMethodInfo methodInfo, Boolean client, XmlReflectionImporter xmlImporter, SoapReflectionImporter soapImporter, String defaultNs) +1971

[InvalidOperationException: Method MyWebService.MethodToAdd can not be reflected.]
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapReflector.ReflectMethod(LogicalMethodInfo methodInfo, Boolean client, XmlReflectionImporter xmlImporter, SoapReflectionImporter soapImporter, String defaultNs) +6307
   System.Web.Services.Description.SoapProtocolReflector.ReflectMethod() +137
   System.Web.Services.Description.ProtocolReflector.ReflectBinding(ReflectedBinding reflectedBinding) +1587
   System.Web.Services.Description.ProtocolReflector.Reflect() +641
   System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescriptionReflector.ReflectInternal(ProtocolReflector[] reflectors) +563
   System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescriptionReflector.Reflect(Type type, String url) +109
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.DocumentationServerType..ctor(Type type, String uri, Boolean excludeSchemeHostPortFromCachingKey) +230
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.DocumentationServerProtocol.Initialize() +473
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing) +122

[InvalidOperationException: Unable to handle request.]
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing) +326
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) +171

[InvalidOperationException: Failed to handle request.]
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) +346
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath) +212
   System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated) +120
   System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +346
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error that is being displayed?

Comment: @JoelEtherton: Please see edited question with complete error details. Well just a wild thought, is it the protected internal properties playing the spoiler?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object XmlSerialization with protected property setters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751448/object-xmlserialization-with-protected-property-setters)

Comment: You're right that this object might be the source of your NRE. It's very possible that the protected setters are to blame though. They are not serializable. The question linked above has some recommendations on how to correct this.

Comment: @JoelEtherton: The accepted answer suggests use of `[XmlIgnore]`. So is the suggestion is to completely ignore the Property?

Comment: That's just one suggestion. You can also remove the protection, implement a custom serializer, use a protected method to perform actual "setting". Since this is likely an object being delivered externally, do you really care if the serialized implementation allows setting?

Comment: I just decorated my class with `DataContract` and members as `DataMember` but when I Run/Debug my web-service I am still receiving same error. Also Yes, this object will be delivered externally and I don't want people to set anything in some properties and are just for view purpose.

Comment: You can't really control the setter remotely through serialization. I'm not really sure why you would want to. Once it's outside of your system, it can be manipulated anyway a consumer likes. If you're concerned about someone using a setter to modify the value in your system, then have your service ignore that property when receiving the object from remote sources.